# best way to create instance of different classes in a loop in iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, instance

I have 3 different UIViewController and I would like to create an instance of each of them in the most efficient way. Right now I create one by one and it works but I guess that might be possible to create all of them in a loop since the only difference is the class name and the frame but I am not sure how to do it. Here is the code

```
Sub1ViewController *sub1 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Sub1"];
sub1.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.scrollViewMain addSubview:sub1.view];

Sub2ViewController *sub2 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Sub2"];
sub2.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.scrollViewMain addSubview:sub2.view];

Sub3ViewController *sub3 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Sub3"];
sub3.view.frame = CGRectMake(2*self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.scrollViewMain addSubview:sub3.view];
```

How do you guys think it could be a better implementation?

Thanks

Comment: Since the frame is different, I'd leave it like this. A loop won't be faster and it doesn't make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```c
- (void)myMethod
{
    [self addControllerWithID:@"Sub1" frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self addControllerWithID:@"Sub2" frame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self addControllerWithID:@"Sub3" frame:CGRectMake(2*self.view.frame.size.width, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}

- (void)addControllerWithID:(NSString *)controllerID frame:(CGRect)frame
{
    UIViewController *controller = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:controllerID];
    controller.view.frame = frame;
    [self.scrollViewMain addSubview:controller.view];
}
```